# Access object from another class to get its variable

Tags: java

I got the object `wolfOne` of the Class `Wolf`, and I need to access to its variable `mAlive` in another Class, how may I don it?

```
    Wolf wolfOne;
```

**//Wolf Class**

```
public class Wolf extends Card {

    public Wolf(){
        mCharacter = "Wolf";
    }

    public void savage(Card card) {
        card.mAlive = false;
    }

}
```

**//Card Class**

```
public class Card {

    //Names
    public String mCharacter;

    //Status
    public static boolean mAlive;
    public static boolean mDefended;
    public static boolean mOwled;
    public static boolean mLastSavaged;
    public static boolean mLastLynched;


    //Constructor
    public Card() {
        // Do Card specific stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: First, don't make all of your booleans static because then, they don't belong to an object. Second, if they are public, you can just access it like this `wolfOne.mAlive`.

Comment: I can't do that, that's why :/

Comment: Then you don't access them by instance. You access them by class: `Wolf.mAlive`.

Comment: In the other class it doesn't recognize wolfOne

Comment: The fact is I got 3 instances of it (3 wolves) and I need to check if all their mAlive values are false, I mean all the 3 values @callyalater

Comment: You don't need `wolfOne` because `mAlive` belongs to the whole `Wolf` class (ie. They are the same for **ALL** instances of Wolf).

Comment: @FET then you _absolutely must_ not have `mAlive` be static, otherwise there's only one `mAlive` value in the whole program.  If different wolves can be differently alive, then `mAlive` _must not_ be static.

Comment: @FET, That is the main issue with your code: your variables are static when they shouldn't be. Why *can't* those variables not be static?

Comment: I made them static as I have other cards too which have that mAlive value, how would I access them otherwise? Shall I make a getter?

Comment: `static` doesn't mean inheritable, it means there is only one copy for all instances (it belongs to the class). Any variable that has a visibility of `protected` or higher (`protected`, `public`, or no visibility modifier) without the `static` qualifier is inherited in subclasses and will belong only to that particular instance.

Comment: Okay, I undertand. I need to have an mAlive value for each Class that extends the Card class, how do i do that?

Comment: Declare it in `Card` with the proper visibility modifier and any class that extends it will automatically inherit its own copy of the variable.

Comment: I tried to, maybe made something wrong, may I have an example? @callyalater

Comment: @FET [Here](http://ideone.com/aoE8b4) is an example.

Comment: https://github.com/SnipCode/LupusInTabula @pczeus

Comment: @Hatward any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Remove static from all of your Class variables - make them instance variables instead. Then provide typical getters/setters for each, allowing clients of the class to retrieve or mutate the value:

```
public class Wolf extends Card {
    public Wolf(){
         setMCharacter("Wolf");
    }

    public void savage(Card card) {
        card.setMAlive(false);
    }
}


    public class Card {

        //Names
        private String mCharacter;

        //Status
        private boolean mAlive;
        private boolean mDefended;
        private static boolean mOwled;
        private static boolean mLastSavaged;
        private static boolean mLastLynched;

        public String getMCharacter(){}
            return mCharacter;
        }

        public void setMCharacter(String value){
            this.mCharacter = value;
        }

        public boolean getMAlive(){
            return mAlive;
        }

        public void setMAlive(boolean alive){
            this.mAlive = alive
        }

        //....So on and so forth
    }
```

Comment: I agree with you that the variables should have accessor/mutator methods on them. It is better design and is more extensible for future development.

Comment: Thank you, I'll let you know tomorrow, for now have a good day!

Comment: The fact is I have a Wolf object called wolfOne (`Wolf wolfOne = new Wolf()`) but in this other class (activity as I'm in android) I can't get a reference to that wolfOne!

Answer (score 1):

`static` has a special meaning in Java. It doesn't mean that the variable or method is inheritable; it means that there is only one of it that belongs to the class, not the instance.

To inherit from a super class, all that is required is that it not `private` and the inheriting classes will get it. The following example shows this relationship.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class A
{
    public String name;
    public boolean isAlive;
    public A()
    {
        name = "A";
        isAlive = true;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public B()
    {
        name = "B";
        isAlive = false;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        A b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();
        b2.name = "B2";
        b2.isAlive = true;
        System.out.println(a.name);
        System.out.println(a.isAlive);
        System.out.println(b1.name);
        System.out.println(b1.isAlive);
        System.out.println(b2.name);
        System.out.println(b2.isAlive);
    }
}
```

And gives this output:

```
A
true
B
false
B2
true
```

This can be run [here](http://ideone.com/aoE8b4).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give you feedback tomorrow taggin' you, for now have a great day!

Comment: The fact is I have a Wolf object called wolfOne (`Wolf wolfOne = new Wolf()`) but in this other class (activity as I'm in android) I can't get a reference to that wolfOne!

Comment: Then you need some way of passing information between contexts in your android application. Without direct access to the instantiated class, you will need some intermediate class that is shared among all your android classes or stored in your Bundle.

Comment: Do you have a public repo that we could see your code? (Android is notorious for being especially verbose due to the several entry points of execution within the life cycle of an activity.)

Comment: Nope, shall I make one in Git?

Comment: That would be nice. Post it in the comments because SO questions should be self-contained (ie. not depend on outside repositories). I will take a look at it and see if there is anything that stands out and if that affects what question you are asking.

Comment: Any chance you got it? Tell me if you can't anymore, it won't be a problem

Comment: I got it, but I haven't had as much time to look at it yet.

Comment: Oh great! Just wanted to know that, by the way guess I've fixed it up: used this to access it: RandomAssignment.medium.getMAlive() It works this way :)

Answer (score 1):

In the card class make the fields private not public, in oo this is called encapsulation or data hiding (look it up). Then simply add a getMAlive method that returns the mAlive value and a setMAlive method which will set it. Now in your wolf class to set mAlive you can with setMAlive(boolean). For external objects you will need to have a reference to your wolf/card and call wolfName.getMAlive()

For card...

```
private boolean mAlive;
public boolean getMAlive(){
  return mAlive;
}
public void setMAlive(boolean value){
  mAlive = value;
}
```

For wolf...

```
public void savage(){
  setMAlive(false);
}
```

For other classes to get mAlive...

```
wolfName.getMAlive()
```

You may consider making your mAlive (and other fields in Card) protected. Protected fields can only be seen by those classes that extend them e.g. wolf. So in wolfs savage method you could do...

```
public void savage(){
  mAlive = false;
}
```

But to set mAlive from other classes you would still need a setter in Card so yeah

I hope this helps :) good luck

Comment: The fact is I have a Wolf object called wolfOne (`Wolf wolfOne = new Wolf()`) but in this other class (activity as I'm in android) I can't get a reference to that wolfOne!